# Text box getting cleared on post back

Tags: infopath, jquery

I have created the textbox in infopath ,Here I have used auto suggest control for a textbox, I will load value and ID in that text box , on selecting a value in auto suggest on the textbox an id will be generated for that selected value, I need to store that is in another text box,on post back the stored ID is getting cleared in that text box is there any solution for this.

```
window.onload = function() {
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000);
}

function getData(){
getState();
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000); //To handle IP's form postback
}


function getState(){ 
var state = []; 
$().SPServices({ 
operation: "GetListItems", 
listName: "state",
CAMLViewFields: "", 
async: false, 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
state.push({label:$(this).attr("ows_Column2"),value:$(this).attr("ows_ID")});   
}); 
} 
}); 

$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T22']").autocomplete({ 
source: state, 
minLength: 2, 
change: function (event, ui) {
},

select: function( event, ui) {
alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.value) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);

$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T22']").val(ui.item.label);
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T23']").val(ui.item.value);
                return false;
        },

focus: function(event, ui){
event.preventDefault();
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T22']").val(ui.item.label);
          return false;
        }
});
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you building the form? by that i mean where is the textbox created? aspx html infopath javascript c#??

Comment: the textbox is created in infopath -@aliSharepoint